# Css: How can I reveal this image from right to left?

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition, right-to-left

CSS newbie here.
I have this image and I want to reveal it from right to left, what do I have to add/change to this code?

```
.arr1 {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:1001px;
    top:920px;
    width:0;
    height:99px;
    background:url(../img/arr1.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:254px 99px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s linear;
    pointer-events: none;

    &:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    width: 254px;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit difficult to give a reliable answer without more code, but from what you posted, change the absolute position of the container to `right` instead of `left` and add the width of the image to the former `left` value, resulting in 1255px:

```
.arr1 {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:1255px;
    top:920px;
    width:0;
    height:99px;
    background:url(../img/arr1.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:254px 99px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s linear;
    pointer-events: none;

    &:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    width: 254px;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    }
}
```

You might also want to add `background-position: right` to `.arr1`, depending how you want the image to be revealed.